# Airflow - PythonOperator required termios module on Window 10

Tags: airflow

I cannot debug the DAG file due to the error in the image below
[image]

I'm working on Windows 10. Anybody may give me the help

Comment: Which Python version do you use? Can it be that your IDE is not set up properly? What happens if you simply execute `python path_to_your_dag_py` in the command line?

Comment: @SergiyKolesnikov, My python version is 3.7 and it through the same issue when I run it in cmd on Windows

Answer (score 3):

termios works only in Unix systems: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tty.html

Airflow does not support Windows (see open [issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/10388) on GitHub)

For development purposes you can work with Airflow on Windows using [Breeze with docker WSL 2](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/BREEZE.rst#docker-in-wsl-2)

Comment: Hi @Elad, that mean I need a Linux PC to code the DAG?